# Rails mountable engine assets in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, production-environment, rails-engines

I built a mountable rails engine in rails 4. I used the engine in another app. In development mode everything runs fine, I can reach the engine without any troubles and all engine assets are displayed properly.

But when I deployed the host app to my server, my scss and js files are not included anymore. All the engine assets are compiled properly. Within the public/assets dir there exists a dir with the engines name and I can find the compiled css and js files plus the images.

But! When I open an engine page from within the host app (so the engine layout-file is rendered) the

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "backbone/application.css", media: "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "backbone/application.js" %>
```

header tags from the engines layout file are translated into:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/backbone/backbone.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/javascripts/backbone/backbone.js"></script>.
```

Obviously these tags don't refer to the assets folder. Furthermore application.js and application.css are renamed into backbone.js and backbone.css.

Can somebody tell me why the assets are compiled during deployment, but the stylesheet javascript tags who should pinpoint the assets are completely wrong?? Did I forget some configuration thing in the engine?

**UPDATE**

config/environment/development.rb:

```
Nad::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

end
```

config/environment/production.rb:

```
Nad::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Whether to fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'arbeidsconferentie.nl' }
end
```

Comment: show your production and development config files

Comment: try changing config.serve_static_assets = false to true.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the hosting provider you are using, you may have to set:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Heroku for example, does not provide nginx or apache to server static assets. Also, if you want to run your rails server in production mode on your locale machine, you need to set this config to `true`.